# Получаю ошибку DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object при запуске pytest

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, path, pytest

Написал для практики простенький автотест и хотел его запустить, он вроде и прошел но есть нюанс... получаю warning cледующего содержания:
"DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object"
Вроде и ничего страшного, тест же пройден, но сердце мое не спокойно, как то неприятно на душе от такого предупреждения, как его можно очистить? точнее сделать так, что бы оно не выскакивало.
Вот код целиком

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager



driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
class TestAUTH:
    def test_auth(self):
        driver.get('https://qa-mesto.praktikum-services.ru/')
        driver.find_element(By.ID, 'email').send_keys('golovanov911@gmail.com')
        driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password').send_keys('WR44tRFU')
        driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'auth-form__button').click()


        WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='root']/div/main/section[1]/div[1]")))

        element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='root']/div/header/div/button").text
        assert element == 'Выйти'

        driver.quit()
```

а приходит об ошибке следующее

```
  /Users/olga/commits/auto_pytest/test_main.py:9: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

как этот вопрос решить?
Заранее спасибо тем кто помог или старался помочь!
[image: коротко о том, как это выглядит в реальности]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значит что `executable_path` устарел, и нужно использовать Service()

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

Comment: то есть такой строчки в коде не достаточно?
```driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())```

нужно дополнительно service устанавливать?
а что тогда этот service делает?

Comment: Ну с ним ошибку не выводит 
Почитайте changelogs по селену https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d6acda7c0254f9681574bf4078ff2001705bf940/py/CHANGES#L101

Comment: я так понял ХромДрайверМэнеджер теперь устарел?)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение которое мне не очень нравится, так что если знаете решение лучше - подскажите.
Суть решения поставить флаг игноррирования таких сообщений
Выглядит он вот так: -W ignore::DeprecationWarning
[image: вот как это выглядит в жизни]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)